# sql query error when using less or equal too

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join, inner-join

Hi guys I have been racking my brain for a while over this.

This query works if I remove the date >= a curtain date. But its throwing up an error when using it.

I am using the Mysql Database.

Here is my code I am using, please bare in mind this is the version before I use prepared statements in pdo.

```
$todaysdate = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime("now - 30 days ago"));

$sql = " 

SELECT *, COUNT(product_order.productId) AS NumberOfOrders FROM product_order 
RIGHT JOIN product ON product_order.productId=product.id 
INNER JOIN product_option_detail ON product_order.productId=product_option_detail.productId 
WHERE product_order.modifiedDate >= {$todaysdate} AND product_order.status = 2 AND product.status = 1 

";
```

The error message I am getting is:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '18:55:40 AND product_order.status = 2 AND product.status = 1 GROUP BY product_o' at line 4

Any help welcome and I thank you for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is now, MySQL will try to interpret the date/time as a symbol instead of a literal value.

```
 $todaysdate = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime("now - 30 days ago"));
```

Turns into something like this:

```
2013-10-11 13:59:44
```

You stuff that value into your SQL statement, which turns into:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(product_order.productId) AS NumberOfOrders FROM product_order 
RIGHT JOIN product ON product_order.productId=product.id 
INNER JOIN product_option_detail ON product_order.productId=product_option_detail.productId 
WHERE product_order.modifiedDate >= 2013-10-11 13:59:44 AND product_order.status = 2 AND product.status = 1
```

You'll need to put the date/time between quotes, so that the SQL becomes:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(product_order.productId) AS NumberOfOrders FROM product_order 
RIGHT JOIN product ON product_order.productId=product.id 
INNER JOIN product_option_detail ON product_order.productId=product_option_detail.productId 
WHERE product_order.modifiedDate >= '2013-10-11 13:59:44' AND product_order.status = 2 AND product.status = 1
```

Alternatively you can let MySQL do the date/time math, like Zane suggests in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11605213/209103):

```
product_order.modifiedDate >=  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
```

Also have a look at [the MySQSL documentation for Date_Sub](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).